# Adding element to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Normally, I wouldnt post this, but it's been driving me crazy for the past 10 hours...

I have 2 list of dictionaries. But they have either none, 1 or 2 things in common. If while iterating the elements on the second list I match a key-value pair from the first list, then I have to add these elements to the first list, at that specific spot

so the first list is like this:

```
list1 = [{'key11':'value11', 'key12':'value12', ...}, {'key11':'value111', 'key121':'value121', ...}]
```

and list2 is like the above mentioned list:

```
list2 = [{'2key11':'value11', 'key12':'value12', '2key13': 'value'...}, {...}]
```

Notice that `key12` is the same on both lists. So the end product I want is this:

```
>list1 = list1 (some operation) list2
>list1
>[{'key11':'value11', 'key12':'value12', '2key11':'value11', ...}, {'key11':'value111', 'key121':'value121', ...}]
```

Notice that in the desired output, I've added all of the second lists dictionary elements to the dictionary that corresponded to key12 in list1(first dictionary).

So far, I've been doing it manually and the results are not good.
my code is this:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    # Now we need to map the panther data as well.
    for pitem in plist:
        # match the id's to the mapped symbols

        if list[i]['key_id1'] == pitem['key_id1']:
            if list[i]['key_id2'] == 'n/a':
                list[i]['key_id2'] = pitem['key_id2']
            list[i]['somekey1'] = panther_item['somekey1']
            list[i]['somekey2'] = panther_item['somekey2']
            list[i]['somekey3'] = panther_item['somekey3'] # <- WHY IS THIS GIVING ME A KEY ERROR AND NOT THE ONE ABOVE IT? Both didnt exist in the dictionary stored in list.
            list[i]['somekey4'] = panther_item['somekey4']
            list[i]['somekey5'] = panther_item['somekey5']

        elif list[i]['key_id2'] == pitem['key_id2']:
            if list[i]['key_id1'] == 'n/a':
                list[i]['key_id1'] = pitem['key_id1']
            list[i]['somekey1'] = panther_item['somekey1']
            list[i]['somekey2'] = panther_item['somekey2']
            list[i]['somekey3'] = panther_item['somekey3']
            list[i]['somekey4'] = panther_item['somekey4']
            list[i]['somekey5'] = panther_item['somekey5']
```

But i'm getting a `keyError` on 'somekey3'. Why 'somekey3' and not 'somekey2'? Both werent there. I put them every time in this iteration. And when I print the 2 lists before the edit they are correct. What could possibly be going wrong here?

Comment: match any key/value pair or just key1?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got the question right, you want to find the union of the two corresponding dictionaries in 2 lists? The code below should accomplish that. Remember that in case the values of the corresponding keys are different, y(list2 dictionaries) will take precedence over x.

```
list3 = []
for x,y in zip(list1, list2):
    z = x.copy()
    for key, value in y.iteritems():
        if value != 'n/a':
            z[key] = value
    list3.append(z)
```

Comment: yeah. I'm aware of that, but in what if something is missing from list1? Remember that I can match up to 2 keys. meaning that if I match one key then the second one is either missing or the same with list1. So if it's missing, it would be nice to fill it up.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "something is missing".  Do you mean that 1) a key is missing, 2) a value, or 3) an entire dictionary? In case 1, where a key is missing from either of the 2 dictionaries being compared, this code will suffice. For case 2, the value for the key in dictionary 2 will take precedence. For case 3, this program will iterate over the shorter of the 2 lists, and compare them.

Comment: we are talking about a list of dictionaries. This is to be used in bioinformatics. So, each node has a dictionary with key-value pairs. the keys are all the same because they are the column names. and the values are the rows. So. imagine a scenario where a row value is missing from the original matrix (set to 'n/a'). it will be filled up by the second list. What if the 1st list has that value stored, and the 2nd list matches the 2nd key but **not** the first. It will override the first key with 'n/a' and thus losing the information. That is the only issue with `update`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem seems to have been partially fixed. **But** I'm getting a keyError saying that one key is missing. `list3` should have all the column names in each node. And every row will either have a value or `'n/a'`.  `keys = list3[0].keys()` I'm doing this to get the keys after your code part and one is missing, I cannot understand why... @Sahil M

Comment: The key that is missing must be absent in list1 and have 'n/a' in list2.

Comment: yes. that's it. But when I do `list1[some_iterator]['missing_key'] = 'somevalue'` Am I not adding it to the dict?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121364/discussion-between-sahil-m-and-mixalis).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I got it right and you want to add all values of dictionaries in list2 to first dictionary in list1 which has 'key12' in it? Following code should do.

```
first_dict = next(d for d in list1 if 'key12' in d)
for d in list2:
    first_dict.update(d)
```

If you want to add them to first dictionary from list1 which has common key(s) with dict from list2 on same position then:

```
first_dict = next(a for a, b in zip(list1, list2) if set(a.keys()) & set(b.keys()))
for d in list2:
    first_dict.update(d)
```